# SDL port Native Client Pepper31 C

Tags: c, sdl, google-nativeclient

I'm having trouble setting up the sdl port for native client, i've found ways to do it for versions previous pepper 19 but nothing for the recent releases. I also need it to be fully in C, no C++.

So if someone knows how to make sdl work with pepper31 please show me the way.

Comment: Can you add some more info about what you've tried, and what fails?

Comment: i finally made it work by copying some makefile information from out/repository/SDL-1.2.14/ 
but now i can't find how to handle messages sent from browser, i'm in C . I should do another post for this ?